# SharePoint list exported from access always shows datasheet list view web part

Tags: 2010, list-view-web-part, microsoft-access

I have exported data from the access table to SharePoint 2010 list.

I have created different views of the same list and want to put on the Site Page. When I am adding the list view web part to the page it always shows up in the datasheet view. The views are not appearing in the standard view pattern on the page.

What should I do to get the data in standard view?